# Understanding Crockford's walk_the_dom ("The Good Parts")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I'm trying to work through to understand Crockford's `walk_the_dom` function below. Here is my logic and the DOM tree I am working with. I don't see when `node.nextSibling` is reached.

[image: Example diagram]

```
function walk(node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        walk(node, func);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};
```

1. func(node) runs a function on the given node.
2. node=node.firstChild() is now equal to the firstChild of document.body, or in this case, **H1**
3. while(node) runs a loop where the **walk function** is run again.
4. func(node) now runs a function on **H1**
5. node = node.firstChild() is now equal to the firstChild of **H1**, also known as **#text** in this case
6. while(node) runs a loop where the **walk function** is run again
7. func(node) runs a function on **#text**
8. node = node.firstChild() --> what is the firstChild of **#text**?
9. when is **node.nextSibling** reached?

Comment: `node = node.nextSibling;` is reached after the `walk` recursion ends (base condition is when `node` is falsy), then the `while` loop starts a new `walk` recursion.

Comment: i don't see why node = node.nextSibling isn't put after the while loop instead. wouldn't that still allow the while loop to run while node is truthy, and then skip to the next sibling when node is falsy? 

EDIT: I think I see it now. It'll recurse through all of the children from the first node, and when there are no more children, it'll skip to the next sibling. took me for a spin, but i think i got it.

Comment: I think you are assuming that calling `walk` inside the loop means that the next line won't run, but it will

Comment: (rewrite of a previous comment) Because there are "multiple levels" of recursion. Assume a dom where each node has multiple siblings and multiple children. The recursive part will dig depth-first, leaving various `while` loops in the call stack to iterate over the siblings of each level. When the recursion hits the base condition (node == falsy), the deepest `while` will advance to the next iteration, thus walking the deepest node's next sibling's descendants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `firstChild` of #text is `null` or `undefined` because there isn't any. JavaScript has what is known as `truthy` values. So `while(null)` is the same as `while(false)`.

Comment: then I don't see how the node = node.nextSibling is ever reached if node is falsy. if every while loop only runs while node is truthy, and the first step of that loop is to run the function again, how can the next sibling be reached when node is falsy? won't that just short-circuit the function execution?

Comment: The recursion ends at falsy, else, it keeps going forever. When it ends, it pops out of the call stack and goes to the next sibling. So, say you are at `#text`, when it pops out, `node` goes back to `H1` and gets set to its sibling `P`. In recursion, each "call stack" has its own `node`. If you set a break point in the browser and check the call stack, you'll see what I mean.